# jQuery mousemove slows down WebGL with three.js

Tags: jquery, three.js, webgl

If I put a `mousemove` handler on my WebGL container the framerate drops drastically while moving the mouse. This only happens if I use the jQuery `mousemove` function, if I instead used the plain `addEventListener` the drop does not happen. Is there something specific that I need to do for jQuery to not have this happen? Or is this a known defect in jquery?

The fast code:

```
document.getElementById('wct').addEventListener( "mousemove", function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop
    sc_outer.light.position.x = x
    sc_outer.light.position.y = y
})
```

The slow code:

```
$('#wct').mousemove( function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop
    sc_outer.light.position.x = x
    sc_outer.light.position.y = y
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The slowdown happens due to frequent calls of jquery to find a specific DOM element (in your case #wct) and check mouse move there.

Event listeners works differently and are designed specifically to catch events.

Comment: I'm not making frequent calls. I do the lookup only to register the callback. The callback code itself is the same.